# Adding a multi-level column to a single-level pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, multi-index

I have a single-level pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[0,0,0],"y":[0,0,0]})
```

which looks like this:

```
    x   y
0   0   0
1   0   0
2   0   0
```

Now I want to add a multi-level column "z" (with two sub-columns "z1 and "z2") to this dataframe, so it'll look like this:

```
    x   y   z
            z1  z2
0   0   0   1   2
1   0   0   1   2
2   0   0   1   2
```

Comment: your life is probably easier if you just add columns `df["z1"] = 1; df["z2"] = 2`

Comment: @anon01  Well in reality I need multiple multi-level columns in my dataframe, each with multiple sub-columns, and I often need to manipulate all sub-columns of a given parent column. If I don't use multi-level columns, then each time I need to do a list comprehension to choose all columns that start with a given string (e.g. all columns that start with a "z", i.e. "z1" and "z2"), so it'll a bit messy. So, if there is an easy way to add multi-level columns to single-level dataframes, that'll make my job easier I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we make the existing columns multi-index:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns,['']*len(df.columns)])
```

and then add new ones indexed by tuples

```
df[('z','z1')] = [1,1,1]
df[('z','z2')] = [2,2,2]
df
```

to get

```
    x   y   z
            z1  z2
0   0   0   1   2
1   0   0   1   2
2   0   0   1   2
```